# How can I plot multiple y variables stacked in a bubble plot?

Tags: python, plot, graph

I am trying to visualise some data for a construction project. Each week, for a few years, different vehicles will be accessing the site. I need to produce a graph showing when each vehicle will be accessing the site. The way I'd like to do this is to have a single graph that shows all vehicles on, so that weeks without any vehicles are empty and can be clearly identified, where as busy weeks will have lots of data visible at the same time.

I want to have the y axis be vehicle type (let's say cars, vans and trucks for now) and x axis be time (weeks of the year). I want to use bubbles to display the number of each vehicle, so if there is a dot at the coordinates (Van, Week 1) you will know that vans will be used during week 1, and the bubble size will tell you how many.

My question is essentially - what is this graph called? I want it to be called something like a "discrete stacked bubble plot" or something but that doesn't exist. Please see my example below. Any ideas on how to do this? Or am I approaching the problem the wrong way?

[Example of what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMWq6.png)

Comment: i dont think a graph like that exists, how do you like multi bar graphs? Alternatively you could use something like a confusion matrix

Comment: What about simple x's instead of bubbles? Ignoring the 3rd dimension of data (i.e. number of vehicles) how would I construct the more basic scatter plot with multiple vehicles on the y axis?

Comment: a more basic scatter plot is a scatter plot :D Youd just have to create value pairs for vehicle and week for each point